# Font has gone a little weird, and posts aren't spaced correctly

Tags: bug, design

This is how questions in the list look on Firefox 7.0 - 10.0:

[image: firefox]

I'm not sure if that's normal but it looks fine.  Chrome 18 (on XP only, see comments) seems to be bolding the font and it's very jagged:

[image: chrome]

And IE 8 looks to be using an entirely different font, and cuts off the lower part of the post when the title wraps more than one line:

[image: ie]

The Chrome thing is probably their bug but I'm assuming the IE one is yours, though of course I don't actually know :P

Comment: For me Chrome 18 beta works correctly, both in linux and win7x64...

Comment: @onik Just upgraded my work machine from XP to Win7 and now it looks OK in Chrome.  I'll note that it may be XP-specific, thanks!

Comment: did you have the Roboto font on your PC? I had it installed on my PC and the site uses that font by default. The font does not display very well on the PC for some reason.

Comment: Are you still seeing this? Anywhere?

Comment: @Shog9 Chrome seems better, but IE8 on XP still uses the wrong font.  I don't see the cutoff issue in IE anymore though.